# Python trying to import a folder as a module

Tags: python, python-import, nix

I am having an odd error whereby when I try to import a class, from a file that is within a subfolder, I get a `ModuleNotFoundError`:

```
from petri.strategyport.strategy import Strategy
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'petri.strategyport'
```

The `strategyport` folder does not contain an `__init__.py`, and I am using python 3.8. Additionally, the `petri` module works in other contexts (when I get an error, I am trying to run it from a NixOS shell). The `sys.path` has the root folder for the `petri` module in it. Could anyone give me a lead as to what might be going wrong here? It seems quite mysterious.

Thanks in advance for any help, and also after the event.

EDIT: the file structure here looks like this:

```
petri/
    __init__.py
    /strategyport/
        strategy.py
```

Where `__init__.py` has `from petri.strategyport.strategy import Strategy`

A FURTHER EDIT:
There are actually a number of other imports done within this package, eg `from petri.asset import Asset`, etcetera. All the single-level (ie, they are at the root directory level, not within their own sub-folder) ones work, whereas none of the multi-level ones do. So there seems to be some fundamental issue here with python mistaking sub-folders for modules. Switching the import syntax from `from petri.xxxx.yyyy import zzzz` to `from xxxx.yyyy import zzzz` makes no difference.

Comment: Please draw folder tree in your question

Answer (score 0):

You should write `from strategyport.strategy import Strategy`

Comment: thanks - unfortunately this doesn't work. The package actually imports quite a lot of other files which are of the form petri.xxxx - I have edited my original post to make things clearer.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
from petri.strategyport.strategy import Strategy
```

to

```
from strategyport.strategy import Strategy
```

there is no need to include the `petri` directory. because your `__init__.py` script is already in that directory. so you just need to write `strategyport.strategy` and that would be enough.

## Or

you can add the parent directory of `petri` to `path`.

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(1, '/path/to/parent/of/petri/')
from petri.strategyport.strategy import Strategy
```

Comment: thanks - I have tried this but unfortunately it doesn't work, please see edit to original question.

Comment: @ChrisJHarris I edited my answer as well. please check if it's Ok now.

Comment: thanks - I have tried that - from my question, 'The sys.path has the root folder for the petri module in it.'

Comment: @ChrisJHarris my bad. I missed the `parent` part at first. please add the **parent** directory of `petri` to the `sys.path`

Comment: thank you - I have tried this but unfortunately with no successful result. It seems to be a particularly weird problem.